# Read QGIS project entry without reading whole project

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-server

I'm trying to read only specific entries from QGIS project in my QGIS server plugin but the problem is that, the projects I'm reading from are usually big, with data from various different sources, loaded over VPN. Loading project from desktop takes few minutes. I need to read only specific entries from properties section.

Is it possible to read only properties without calling read method on QgsProject instance?

I think that read method causes reading all the data sources, which is opposite to what I want to achieve. I know that I could read project as plain xml file but still it would be nice to use QGIS for that.